# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers　エラーについて

Tags: python, python3, json, api, windows-10

Pythonの初心者です。
AzureのFace APIを使って、人物画像から感情を数値化するサンプルプログラムを実行しているのですが、エラーが出てしまっています。

以下がエラーの抜粋となります。

```
File "emotion_2.py", line 65, in <module>
    top = x['faceRectangle']['top']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

ソースコード(抜粋)

```
def emotion(image):
    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'apiの取得Key',
    }

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    })
```

```
img = '人物画像のパス' 

data = open(img,'br')
a = emotion(data)
json_dict = json.loads(a)
print(json.dumps(json_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=1))
print("main Start!!")
for x in json_dict:
    top = x['faceRectangle']['top']
    left = x['faceRectangle']['left']
    width = x['faceRectangle']['width']
    height = x['faceRectangle']['height']

    anger = x['scores']['anger']
    contempt = x['scores']['contempt']
    disgust = x['scores']['disgust']
    fear = x['scores']['fear']
    happiness = x['scores']['happiness']
    neutral = x['scores']['neutral']
    sadness = x['scores']['sadness']
    surprise = x['scores']['surprise']
```

幾らか同様のエラーについて検索したのですが、文字列に変更?
してしまっていると。
しかしそれらを見ても自分ではあまり理解できておりません。
どうかご教示いただきますよう、お願いいたします。

Comment: `for x in json_dict: ...` としていますので、`x` は `json_dict`(dict型のオブジェクト)のキー(文字列)になっているのではないでしょうか。for loop は必要なくて `top = json_dict['faceRectangle']['top']` などとしてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
実際に top = json_dict['faceRectangle']['top']に直したところ、
KeyError: 'faceRectangle'とのエラーが出ました。
こちらでも原因について調べてみますが、何かご存じでしたら教えてもらえませんか。
ちなみにこのソースコードは
https://orangelab.jp/blog/microsoft-emotion-python/
をそのまま引用しているので、そもそもエラーが出るのが
気になるところなんですが。

Comment: もしかしたら `for x in json_dict:` は `for x in json_dict.values():` が正しいのかもしれません。ただ、コードでは 1 枚の画像のみを処理しているので、for loop の必要は無い様に見えますね… つまり、`top = json_dict.values()[0]['faceRectangle']['top']` ではないかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらも色々と試してみます。
回答をいただきまして、誠にありがとうございます。